# почему после того как я пишу npm start мне выбивает новую консоль?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Почему после того как  я пишу npm start мне выбивает новую консоль
Вот мой код

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const { electron } = require('process');

const  {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;
let mainWindow; 

app.on("ready", function() {

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname,'index.html'),
    protocol:'file:',
    slashes: true
    }));
});
```

и html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>jsmpeg-vnc</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #111;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: #555;
        }
        body.desktop .mobile-only { display: none; }
        body.mobile .desktop-only { display: none; }

        #videoCanvas {
            /* Always stretch the canvas to 100%, regardless of its
            internal size. */
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .keys {
            position: relative;
        }
        .key {
            color: #fff;
            float: left;
            width: 72px;
            height: 48px;
            padding-top: 24px;
            background-color: #5bcbeb;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .key-small {
            height: 28px;
            padding-top: 8px;
        }
        #key-up {left: 40px; top: 0px; }
        #key-down {left: 40px; top: 88px; }
        #key-left {left: 160px; top: 0px; }
        #key-right {left: 240px; top: 0px; }
        #key-esc {left: 160px; top: 124px; }
        #key-enter {left: 240px; top: 124px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="videoCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

    <div class="keys mobile-only">
        <div class="key" data-code="38" id="key-up">UP</div>
        <div class="key" data-code="40" id="key-down">DOWN</div>
        <div class="key" data-code="39" id="key-right">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="key" data-code="37" id="key-left">LEFT</div>
        
        <div class="key key-small" data-code="27" id="key-esc">ESC</div>
        <div class="key key-small" data-code="13" id="key-enter">ENTER</div>
    </div>

    <script>require('./render.js');</script>

    <!-- текст 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsmpg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsmpg-vnc.js"></script>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а на чем пишите?

Comment: скиньте start script из package,json. Почету-то мне кажется что у вас там 2 npm run скрипта

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, Electron js

Comment: `{
  "name": "komigor_electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.1"
  }
}
`@Aziz Umarov

Comment: попробуйте поменять на "start": "electron ."